# CSS переменные, конкатенация

Tags: css3

Пытаюсь вынести путь до картинок в переменную, а в дальнейшем склеить с именем картинки.

Моя попытка не сработала, возможно ли это?

```
:root {
  --image-path: 'assets/images/';
}
```

Хочу использовать примерно так

```
div {
  background: url(var(--image-path) + 'image.png');
}
```

Comment: Никто не подскажет?)

Comment: var невозможно использовать внутри url... но это дело легко решается через JS.